# TM1 : Error :Incorrect syntax Near '|' (inserting numeric value into sql query)

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-tm1

I am trying to insert a numeric variable 'Value ' into a decimal database column.

I used this query syntax :

```
SQL= 'INSERT INTO DB_Archive VALUES ( '''| dim1|''' , '''| dim2|''', '|Value|') ';
```

But it seems it's not correct way to declare a numeric column, which gave me this error :

```
Error : Incorrect syntax Near '|'
```

I tried then converting the numeric value to a string value like this :

```
zAmoun= NumberToString(Value);
SQL= 'INSERT INTO DB_Archive VALUES ( '''| dim1|''' , '''| dim2|''', '''|StringToNumber(zAmount)|''') ';
```

But it was a bad move to do , since it worked in the compilation and didnt return no error but in the execution it return this error here since the table column is a decimal :

```
Error : Error Converting data Type varchar to numeric
```

I would love if someone could help me know what is the correct syntax to declare a numeric column in sql query , since the first declaration is not working.

I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this Information can help you:

At the start: Please don't start variable names with upper cases. Make something like vSQL or sqlRequest.

You try to build a SQL-Command with a string. The hole string cannot include numeric. TM1 is really strict with it. Every number must be converted to String.

```
vsValue = NumberToString(value);
vsSQL= 'INSERT INTO DB_Archive VALUES ( '''| dim1|''' , '''| dim2|''', '''|vsValue|''') ';
```

Maybe your SQL-Target need the value in a specific form. For example with a "," as decimal seperator. Therefore you can us the command `NumberToStringEx()`.

```
vsValue = NumberToStringEx(value, '0.0####', ',', '.');
vsSQL= 'INSERT INTO DB_Archive VALUES ( '''| dim1|''' , '''| dim2|''', '''|vsValue|''') ';
```

[here you find additional information](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD29G_2.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_prism_gs.2.0.0.doc/r_tm1_ref_tifun_numbertostringex.html)

With quotation marks you will give your sql-target the information, if the value is numeric or string. So maybe it's necessary to delete the quotation marks:

```
vsValue = NumberToString(value);
vsSQL= 'INSERT INTO DB_Archive VALUES ( '''| dim1|''' , '''| dim2|''', '|vsValue|') ';
```